# Alert messages do not always show up on production (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My alert messages do not always show up on production (hosted on Heroku). However, it always shows up on development.

Here's the bit of code from the controller:

```
flash[:warning] = "Please specify an input"
redirect_to(root_url)
```

And I render it in application.html with the following code:

```
!-- Display notices -->
<div class="<%='shift_no_breadcrumb' if yield(:crumbs).blank? %>">
    <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, value, :class => ("alert alert-#{key}")) %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

It seems very sporadic on production. Out of 10 tries performing the same exact action, the message may show up anywhere from 3-6 times. I have also checked the source code and can verify that sometimes the message shows up and sometimes it does not. Does this have something to do with the order in which assets are loaded? I am very puzzled with this issue....Does anyone have any insight as to what is behind this?

Comment: Do you have before_filters, it's possible that you before filters redirecting the control multiple times so flash gets empty. Try to find way to reproduce the issue, so that we can help you

Comment: Nope, not before filters at all. I will try. Also, it is not just for flash messages from one controller. This problem happens when I issue flash messages from other controllers as well. The message shows up sporadically in production..

Comment: Have you tried sending the message "text" to the logger each time? I immediately thought you had an issue with "Javascript", however it seems you're using standard `div`s - the best way to test this is to see if your action is setting the request each time -- by putting a `Rails.logger.info("your information")` in the action

Comment: It looks like the message is sent to the logger every time, but it doesn't always appear on the HTML. Is there something wrong with the code I am using in application.html?